# Prove that the direction ratios of the line of intersection of two planes $\vec r\cdot(a\hat i+ b\hat j+ c\hat k)=m $ and...

Tags: 3d

> Prove that the direction ratios of the line of intersection of two planes $\vec r\cdot(a\hat i+ b\hat j+ c\hat k)=m $ and $\vec r\cdot(d\hat i+ e\hat j+ f\hat k)=n$ is given by $\begin{vmatrix}\hat i&\hat j&\hat k\\a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{vmatrix}$ where m and n are any two real numbers.

Transforming into coordinate form, the vectors are $ax+by+cz=m$ and $dx+ey+fz=n$ .Assuming $x=t$ we can solve for $x$, $y$ and $z$ by converting into coordinate form but that method will be very long. Is there a more intuitive way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The line of intersection of two planes is perpendicular to the normal of each of the planes.

Comment: okay, how do we proceed further?

Comment: Could anyone experienced here please tell me if I should write the answer. I was recently told that we should not answer Problem- statement questions, following which I only suggested a hint while not being sure if this is a PSQ, though the OP mentioned that she tried to solve the two equations of plane to get the equation of line!

Comment: @amankushwala yes lol I just realised you were talking about the cross product, no need for the answer thanks